# Moving drawings on screen

Tags: java, swing

I have this code for moving some drawings using variable `i` referring to the index in the array, but when I run the code I just get the head of the 'snake' printed in the top left corner of my screen and it doesn't move.

Any idea why this may not be working?

Here's the minimal reproducible example

```
public class SandBox {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new GameFrame();

    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    GameFrame() {
        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Snake Game");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT)/UNIT_SIZE;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    final int[] x = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int[] y = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;

    GamePanel(){
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        startGame();
    }

    public void startGame(){
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT/UNIT_SIZE; i++){
            g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i*UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++){
            if (i == 0){
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                g.setColor(new Color(45,180,0));
            }
            g.fillRect(x[i],y[i],UNIT_SIZE,UNIT_SIZE);
        }
    }

    public void move(){

        for(int i = bodyParts;i>0;i--) {
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(running) {
            move();
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I attempted to use SwingWorker, but I don't fully understand it yet, however this specific animation is usually done with the process I've used here so I'm hoping it would work fine.

Comment: First, are you certain running is appropriately set to `true`.  And and it isn't really possible to tell what is going on with just a few code fragments.  Also, keep in mind that too much processing in the EDT can affect your app.  A [mre] that demonstrates the problem would be helpful  And keep it small.

Comment: We have no idea what your painting code does or where the "running" variable is set to true. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: You need to understand the event dispatch thread if you want to use any animation. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html For a lesson on how to use timers (which is what you need here) see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: This should be everything for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your code and got your snake to draw and move.  Here's the revised GUI.

[image: Snake GUI]

The green block is the head of the snake.  The yellow blocks are the body of the snake.

The snake is moving east at a rate of one block a second.

I created a `Snake` plain Java getter / setter class to hold a snake.  I modified the `move` method in your `GamePanel` class to use the `List` that holds the snake.

I rearranged the `JFrame` method calls in your `GameFrame` class so they would execute in the correct order.

I commented out some code so I could test easier.

You'll need to code the rest of the snake game.  I hope this helps you get going.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post this as one block of code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SnakeGameGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SnakeGameGUI().new GameFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public GameFrame() {
            this.setTitle("Snake Game");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.add(new GamePanel());
            this.pack();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
        static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
        static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
        static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / UNIT_SIZE;
        static final int DELAY = 1000;
//      final int[] xUnit = new int[GAME_UNITS];
//      final int[] yUnit = new int[GAME_UNITS];

        Timer timer;
        Random random;
        private Snake snake;

        public GamePanel() {
            random = new Random();
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            this.snake = new Snake();
            startGame();
        }

        public void startGame() {
            timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            draw(g);
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
//          for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
//              g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
//              g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
//          }
            
            int count = 0;
            for (Point point : snake.getCells()) {
                int x = UNIT_SIZE * point.x;
                int y = UNIT_SIZE * point.y;
                if (count == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
                g.fillRect(x, y, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                count++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            move();
            repaint();
        }
        
        public void move() {
            List<Point> cells = snake.getCells();
            Point point = cells.get(0);
            int x = point.x;
            int y = point.y;
            int direction = snake.getDirection();
            
            /** 1 = North
             *  2 = East
             *  3 = South
             *  4 = West
             */
            switch (direction) {
            case 1:
                y -= 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                x += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                y += 1;
                break;
            case 4:
                x -= 1;
                break;
            }
            
            snake.removeCell(cells.size() - 1);
            snake.addCell(0, new Point(x, y));
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Snake {
        
        /** 1 = North
         *  2 = East
         *  3 = South
         *  4 = West
         */
        private int direction;
        
        private List<Point> cells;
        
        public Snake() {
            this.cells = new ArrayList<>();
            this.cells.add(new Point(5, 10));
            this.cells.add(new Point(4, 10));
            this.cells.add(new Point(3, 10));
            this.cells.add(new Point(2, 10));
            this.cells.add(new Point(1, 10));
            this.cells.add(new Point(0, 10));
            this.direction = 2;
        }

        public int getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setDirection(int direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public List<Point> getCells() {
            return cells;
        }

        public void addCell(int index, Point point) {
            this.cells.add(index, point);
        }
        
        public void removeCell(Point point) {
            this.cells.remove(point);
        }
        
        public void removeCell(int index) {
            this.cells.remove(index);
        }
    }

}
```